# Motor Phase Reverse Direction

Tags: motor, three-phase

We have a mobile belt conveyor driven by a 380V three phase motor.There are two separate lines of conveyors in a conveying system. The mobile conveyor is running in forward direction in one line but why it is in the reverse direction on the other line? What could be the causes?

Comment: Does each section have a separate three phase motor?

Comment: Yes, the two lines are in parallel using separate three phase motors.

Answer (score 3):

One of the motors is connected differently to three phase mains so it runs in different direction.

Some 3 phase mains plugs contain a switch to swap 2 phases to change direction of motors.

Comment: ... and even without a switch, swapping two of the phases always reverse the direction.

Comment: The actual is three motors in sequence) are in one source only. The reverse rotation happened in 2 of the 3 motors. Why?

Comment: @BombodiPerj There must be a wiring difference in some connections between motor and the one power source you mention.